# Convert spaces, umlauts and special character letters for link

Tags: php, html, entity

## How can I make the browser accept the letters umlauts and spaces without decoding?

```php
 $str = 'Häuser & Hühner können nicht „Hallo“ sagen!';
 $strent = htmlentities($str);
 $strurl = rawurlencode($str);
 echo '<a href="'.$strent.'">'.$str.'</a>';
 echo '<a href="'.$strurl.'">'.$str.'</a>';
```

**unexpected output**

```html
<a href="Häuser & Hühner können nicht „Hallo“ sagen!">Häuser & Hühner können nicht „Hallo“ sagen!</a>
<a href="Häuser%20%26%20Hühner%20können%20nicht%20„Hallo“%20sagen%21">Häuser & Hühner können nicht „Hallo“ sagen!</a>
```

**expected ouput**

```html
<a href="H&auml;user%20%26%20H&uuml;hner%20k&ouml;nnen%20nicht%20&bdquo;Hallo&ldquo;%20sagen%21">Häuser & Hühner können nicht „Hallo“ sagen!</a>
```

Comment: When are you seeing the decoding? You should likely be using URL encode. If that is really a URL.

Comment: updated my question. It doesn't work with rawurlencode () either

Comment: Why is `H&auml;user%20` expected? That's merging two encodings. `Häuser & Hühner können nicht „Hallo“ sagen!` in a URL should be `H%C3%A4user+%26+H%C3%BChner+k%C3%B6nnen+nicht+%E2%80%9EHallo%E2%80%9C+sagen%21` you could double encode the accented characters if the entities are needed where decoding.

Answer (score 0):

**Current working result**

```php
$str = 'Häuser & Hühner können nicht „Hallo“ sagen!';
$strurl = rawurlencode($str);

echo '<a href="'.$strurl.'">'.$str.'</a>';
```

```html
<a href="Häuser%20%26%20Hühner%20können%20nicht%20„Hallo“%20sagen%21">Häuser & Hühner können nicht „Hallo“ sagen!</a>
```